# Error while trying to unmarshal EDMX with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm new to JAXB and I'm trying to un-marshal a certain XML.
The XML is:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="smallApp">         
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
```

I have built a schema of classes that looks like this:
Edmx.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "edmx:Edmx")
public class Edmx {

@XmlElement(name = "edmx:DataServices")
private DataService dataService;

public DataService getDataService() {
    return dataService;
}
}
```

DataService.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "edmx:DataServices")
public class DataService {

@XmlElement(name = "Schema")
private Schema schema;

public Schema getSchema() {
    return schema;
}
 }
```

and Schema.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Schema")
public class Schema {

}
```

Then, I have built a sample method that unmarshal the above XML with the Edmx.class as such:

```
public class Parser {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File fXmlFile = new File("somePathToXML");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fXmlFile);
        Edmx edmx = load(Edmx.class, inputStream);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * loads an object from an xml file
 * @param <T>
 * @param type
 * @param file
 * @return
 */
public static <T> T load(Class<? extends T> type, InputStream stream) {
    try {

        if(stream.available() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T obj = (T) um.unmarshal(stream);
        return obj;
    } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
        System.out.println("failed to read from InputStream");
        jaxbe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("InputStream is empty");
        return null;
    }

}
 }
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx", local:"Edmx"). Expected elements are <{}Schema>,<{}edmx:DataServices>,<{}edmx:Edmx>
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
```

This is strange, since I have no elements that it does not expect :(
Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

**package-info**

You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification for your model.  Below I've specified that unless otherwise specified, all elements will be qualified by the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx` namespace.  I have also specified that the preferred prefix for that namespace is edmx, and that `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx` should be the default namespace.

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx",
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
                @XmlNs(prefix="edmx", namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"),
                @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm")
        }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package forum14875956;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Edmx**

Now no namespace information needs to be specified on the  `Edmx` class.

```
package forum14875956;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Edmx")
public class Edmx {

    @XmlElement(name = "DataServices")
    private DataService dataService;

    public DataService getDataService() {
        return dataService;
    }

}
```

**DataService**

On the `DataService` class we will specify a namespace on the mapping for the `schema` property.

```
package forum14875956;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class DataService {

    @XmlElement(name = "Schema", namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm")
    private Schema schema;

    public Schema getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

}
```

**Schema**

You can override the namespace qualification for the properties on the `Schema` class using the `@XmlType` annotation.

```
package forum14875956;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm")
public class Schema {

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum14875956;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Edmx.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14875956/input.xml");
        Edmx edmx = (Edmx) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(edmx, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema/>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: It helped - the error is no longer thrown. Thanks for That! Another question I have though: Now, When adding the namespace to is own 'parameter' (on the EDMX object and DataService) I get an Edmx.java object with 'dataService=null'. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user1027133 - I have updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It seems to work now. I'll just try to understand better what just happen (cause I need to expand my XML of course) :) Thank you very much though! It was really helpful....