# Null values while un-marshalling XML with namspaces using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an issue while un-marshalling simple XML (a subset of CSDL) using JAXB.
Someone already tried to assist me in the past ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875956/error-while-trying-to-unmarshal-edmx-with-jaxb)), however it is partially worked and I don't know what to do...
Please consider the following XML:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="myNS">
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

As I was told, I have a **package-info.java** file that looks like (in the same package):

```
@XmlSchema(
  namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx",
  elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
  xmlns={
          @XmlNs(prefix="edmx", namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"),
          @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"),
          @XmlNs(prefix="m", namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")                                
  }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package com.sap.ndb.studio.rdl.csdlparser.jaxb.objects;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

In addition, I have the following data structure:

**Edmx.java**

```
package com.sap.ndb.studio.rdl.csdlparser.jaxb.objects;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Edmx")
public class Edmx {

    @XmlElement(name = "DataServices")
    private DataService dataService;

    public DataService getDataService() {
          return dataService;
    }
}
```

**DataService.java**

```
package com.sap.ndb.studio.rdl.csdlparser.jaxb.objects;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class DataService {

    @XmlElement(name = "Schema")
    private Schema schema;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DataServiceVersion")
    private double version;

    public Schema getSchema() {
      return schema;
    }
 }
```

**Schema.java**

```
package com.sap.ndb.studio.rdl.csdlparser.jaxb.objects;

@XmlRootElement
public class Schema {
  ....
}
```

Notice: in Schema.java I have some implementation which does not related to the XML so I have took it off (internal logic).
**After un-marshalling the XML using the JAXB, The returned Edmx object contains null values both in 'schema' and 'version' members, although I have mentioned all xmlns parameters in my package-info.java.


Anyone? :(**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while trying to unmarshal EDMX with JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875956/error-while-trying-to-unmarshal-edmx-with-jaxb)

Comment: This is not duplicate since I asked both questions :) I have mentioned this at the beginning (link was added).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

In my answer to one of your previous questions I provider a mapping for the model from this question.

- [Error while trying to unmarshal EDMX with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875956/error-while-trying-to-unmarshal-edmx-with-jaxb)

I have updated this answer to address the following comment that you made:

> Why should I declare
>   'namespace=schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm'; in my @XmlElement?
>   sorry for being annoying (this is my first experience with JAXB) but I
>   just gonna have a long XML with many @XmlElement nodes similar to the
>   'Schema' and I would like to declare the namespace for them only
>   once...

You can reduce the number of times you need to declare a namespace by organizing your model classes into different packages based on the namespace that they correspond to.

**Package 1 for Namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx`**

***package-info***

For each package we will use the `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification.  In this example we only need to specify the namespace for this particular package.

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx",
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
                @XmlNs(
                    prefix="edmx", 
                    namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
                ),
        }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package forum14875956.edmx;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

***Edmx***

The XML elements corresponding to the `Edmx` class will be namespace qualified according to what we defined on the `@XmlSchema` annotation for this package.

```
package forum14875956.edmx;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Edmx")
public class Edmx {

    @XmlElement(name = "DataServices")
    private DataService dataService;

    public DataService getDataService() {
        return dataService;
    }

}
```

***DataService***

The `DataService` class contains a reference to a class corresponding to a different XML namespace.  If the `Schema` class was in the same package we could use the `@XmlElement` annotation to override the namespace qualification.  Since `Schema` is in a different package we can use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation.  This tells JAXB to derive the element information from the root element configured for that class.

```
package forum14875956.edmx;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import forum14875956.schema.Schema;

public class DataService {

    //@XmlElement(namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm", name="Schema")
    @XmlElementRef
    private Schema schema;

    public Schema getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

}
```

**Package 2 for Namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm`**

Again we will use the `@XmlSchema` to declare the namespace information for the second package.

***package-info***

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm",
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
                @XmlNs(
                    prefix="", 
                    namespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"
                )
        }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package forum14875956.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

***Schema***

The elements in the `Schema` class will be namespace qualified based namespace information in the `@XmlSchema` annotation for its package.

```
package forum14875956.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Schema")
public class Schema {

}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You need to include the namespace URI on the mapping for the `schema` property:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataService {

    @XmlElement(name = "Schema" , namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm")
    private Schema schema;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DataServiceVersion")
    private double version;

    public Schema getSchema() {
      return schema;
    }
 }
```

**Full Example**

A little while I ago I answered one of your questions providing a complete mapping for this model:

- [Error while trying to unmarshal EDMX with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875956/error-while-trying-to-unmarshal-edmx-with-jaxb/14876026#14876026)

Comment: The example you gave me is true, however why declaring on "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" with prefix 'm' in Package-Info.java is not enough as we did with the Edmx and the DataService? Why should I declare 'namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm' in my @XmlElement? sorry for being annoying (this is my first experience with JAXB) but I just gonna have a long XML with many @XmlElement nodes similar to the 'Schema' and I would like to declare the namespace for them only once...

Comment: @user1027133 - Based on the `@XmlSchema` annotation, your JAXB impl is going to apply the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx` to any element corresponding to classes in that package that don't have another namespace specified.  You can set things up so that the classes corresponding to a particular namespace are in their own package.